# PHP - Displaying number of people that chose that item?

Tags: php, mysql

My website is for my school, and we're making a login page that displays how many students have signed up for particular classes.

I'm confused on how to get this to work. Every time someone chooses a class, it should tell the database that 1 person chose that particular class. Then I would echo that this many people chose that class.

I created a variable for $students, and also added a table 'students' in the database. I'm still running into trouble. Here is my code. I echoed students in every period.

```
$names = $db->fetchAll("select `name` from `classes`");

$login = $_POST['login'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$update = $_POST['update'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pic = $_POST['pic'];
$created_on = $_POST['created_on'];

$per1 = $_POST['per1'];
$per2 = $_POST['per2'];
$per3 = $_POST['per3'];
$per4 = $_POST['per4'];
$per5 = $_POST['per5'];
$per6 = $_POST['per6'];
$per7 = $_POST['per7'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$logged_in = $_COOKIE['logged_in'];

$bday = "$month $day $year";
$students = $_POST['students'];

if (empty($logged_in) ) {
    header("location: login.php");
}

$info = $db->fetchRow("select * from `profile` 
                       where `username` =?", array($logged_in));

if ($update == "Update"){
    $data = array(
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'email' => $email,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'pic' => $pic,
        'per1' => $per1,
        'per2' => $per2,
        'per3' => $per3,
        'per4' => $per4,
        'per5' => $per5,
        'per6' => $per6,
        'per7' => $per7,
        'bday' => $bday,
        'students' => $students
    );

    $db->update($data, "profile", "id=?", array($info['id']));
}

$info = $db->fetchRow("select * from `profile` 
                       where `username` =?", array($logged_in));
```

Comment: `$bday = "$month $day $year";` change this one to `$bday = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;`

Comment: @prava that does not answer my question.

Comment: If you can store the number of student count according to the class in a file system, instead of DB, then without login, you can get the data from that file and show accordingly. And when a student register into class, then with updating DB, you have to update the count in file system. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "file system" ... can you explain?